# Can I build object json in serialization (newton) from a method?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, .net-core

I have a base abstract

```
public abstract class absBase
{
    public int A {get;set;}
    public string B {get;set;}
    public abstract string Generate()
}

public class FirstClass : absBase
{
    public override string Generate()
    {
          //Mapping of certain properties and some calcs
          return ObjectRepresentationInStringOrObject;
    }
}
```

Now what I would like to do is

```
 var a = new FirstClass();
 string jsonRep = JsonConvert.Serialize(a);
```

and to have jsonRep be the string that returns from Generate().
the Idea is to build a tree of objects for serialization but the leaves would be generated exatcly as I want them.
I've tried ISerializeable in the root object that implements the GetObjectData and calls the Generate abstract method , but its never called and just returnes the properties of the objects.

Comment: If using Json.Net then use a custom converter

Comment: If you really want `jsonRep be the string that returns from Generate()` then why do you need Json at all? just do `var jsonRep = a.Generate();`?

Comment: I am trying to create an object tree , not all is going to be of type FirstClass and I prefer to control the output from the class type and not from the converter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a custom converter for the type, that will call the desired member

```
public class AbsBaseConverter : JsonConverter {

    public override bool CanRead {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
        return objectType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(absBase));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        var obj = (absBase)value;
        var json = obj.Generate();
        writer.WriteRaw(json);
    }
}
```

`objectType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(absBase))` in the `CanConvert` method will return true for all derived types of `absBase`.

Next, decorate the base type accordingly

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(AbsBaseConverter))]
public abstract class absBase {
    public int A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public abstract string Generate();
}
```

and when calling

```
var a = new FirstClass();
string jsonRep = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);
```

the converter will call the `Generate` member when serializing.